# Cascading Dropdown in Powerapps from Lookup list

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp

I have three List one for event,Agenda,and Schedule. Event have Event column with value M1 and M2 and Agenda have Agenda column value A1 and A2 now Schedule list have Lookup column from Agenda and Event . 
Now Using Schedule list i want to create Cascading dropdown where i had  mapped value from Agenda and Event

```
Schedule list
Event Agenda
M1    A1
M1    A2
M2    A2
M2    A1
```

Have created two dropdowns in Powerapps For first Dropdown1 written rule on item

```
Distinct('Schedule list','Event'.Value)
```

Second Dropdown rule  written on item
`Filter('Schedule list','Event'.Value=Dropdown1.Selected.Result)` where i am unable to set value for lookup so it returning me blank values